# Error with materize css and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, materialize

I had a system in PHP that works perfect but I was not responsive, so I'm trying to integrate materialize css http://materializecss.com/
The first thing I changed was my navbar. Now my navbar is responsive, but it has a problem, when I click on any navbar option my PHP session is deleted.

I do not think the problem is PHP, because the only thing I did was replace the header.php file

All my php pages do the following "require_once (" header.php ")

In addition all pages have a security check

```
if(isset($_SESSION["User"]))
        {
            if($_SESSION["User"]["range"] == "admin")
            {
             //Admininistrador
             echo '<script language=Javascript>location.href="profile-admin.php?error=E002";</script>';
            }

        }
        else{ //No inicio sesion
             echo '<script language=Javascript>location.href="login.php?error=E001";</script>';
        }
```

My new header uses the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/       
<link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

And also uses:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
        $(".dropdown-button").dropdown();
      })
    </script>
```

Please I need help.
Remember that the only thing I did was to change my header.php file, before it worked perfect.

Comment: So if you remove materialize - session stays the same?

Comment: If I remove new header.php, then the system is ok. But I need to "materialize" to make it adaptable.

Comment: I suppose you materialized html just places some logout link everywhere in a header.

Comment: No. The links are well placed.
Even if I play F5, the session is erased. It is a mistake that I can not explain.
The only thing that occurs to me is that materialize use some technology that I must indicate something